# Miro Video Problem

Tags: video, vlc

I had a situation about subtitles on VLC. I wasn't able to solve it, then I decided to find another video player on Linux. I googled "Best Media players for Linux". I actually found several options, and MIRO was one of the best. I've installed it without any problems but it does not work or I did something wrong.

Miro opens every video/music I got, but there is only sound. I can't find video screen and it does not show any video screen. Also, when I try to search for a folder on my computer it is not listing MP4, MKV and AVI files.

Is there any solution for this?